# Last Wednesday of every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to work out the last Wednesday for each month in a range of dates.

I have the code for calculating the last Wednesday, but my cte doesn't seem to step through the months correctly.

Current code:

```
declare @S_Date date
declare @E_Date date

set @S_Date='2016-01-31'  --eomonth of first month
set @E_Date='2016-06-15'  --ides of last month ( can actually be any day that is
                          --not equal to or after the last Wednesday of the month)

;with LW(D_Date) as
    (
    select dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,@S_Date)/7*7+2,0) 
    union all
    select dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,eomonth(D_Date,1))/7*7+2,0)
    from LW
    where D_date<@E_Date
    )
select d_date
from LW
```

changing the `eomonth` to

```
select dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,dateadd(mm,1,D_Date))/7*7+2,0)
```

doesn't seem to work either

Expected results:

> 2016-01-27
>   2016-02-24
>   2016-03-30
>   2016-04-27
>   2016-05-25
>   2016-06-29

Comment: When you say you have the code for calculating last Wednesday, where do you have it?   How do you figure you can calculate which day is Weds without some use of `WeekDay`?

Comment: Just an aside... **ides** was used for the date because it was cute, not because of any overriding reason to have to use that date.

Comment: @TabAlleman, the code for last Wednesday was from another site, and required use of the last day of the month, which is why I used EOMONTH, and set the initial date to the last day of January. @@DATEFIRST can be considered to be the default US setting, 7 or Sunday

Comment: Ok, I guess that the code is based on the weekday of day 0, which is a known quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with [`EOMONTH()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`DATEFROMPARTS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
declare @S_Date date
declare @E_Date date

set @S_Date='2016-01-31'  --eomonth of first month
set @E_Date='2016-06-15'  --ides of last month ( can actually be any day that is
                          --not equal to or after the last Wednesday of the month)

;With Date (Date) As
(
    Select  DateFromParts(Year(@S_Date), Month(@S_Date), 1) Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date) 
    From    Date
    Where   Date < EOMonth(@E_Date)
)
Select  Max(Date) As LastWednesday
From    Date
Where   DatePart(WeekDay, Date) = 4
Group By Year(Date), Month(Date)
Option  (MaxRecursion 0)
```

> Output

```
LastWednesday
2016-01-27
2016-02-24
2016-03-30
2016-04-27
2016-05-25
2016-06-29
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a slightly different approach without the partitioning... result should be the same:

```
declare @S_Date date
declare @E_Date date

set @S_Date='2016-01-31'  --eomonth of first month
set @E_Date='2016-06-15'  --ides of last month ( can actually be any day that is
                          --not equal to or after the last Wednesday of the month)

;With Date (Date, WD) As
(
    Select  DateFromParts(Year(@S_Date), Month(@S_Date), 1), DatePart(WeekDay, DateFromParts(Year(@S_Date), Month(@S_Date), 1)) AS wd
    Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date), DatePart(WeekDay, DateAdd(Day, 1, Date)) AS wd
      From    Date
      Where   Date < EOMonth(@E_Date)
)
Select  Max(Date) As LastWednesday
  From    Date
  Where   wd = 4
  group by MONTH(Date)
  Option  (MaxRecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) ..I have a calendar table and below screenshot shows you how simple it is check or get last wednesday of each month..

**query used:**

```
select * from dbo.calendar where year='2013' and wkdname='Wednesday'
and last=1
```

**Output of above query which you can modify as per your requirement:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is rather straightforward solution with `eomonth`.

```
declare @s_date date='2016-01-01',@e_date date='2016-12-31' --date range
;with eom_tbl as (--CTE
--anchor from start date
select EOMONTH(@s_date,0) eom,datepart(weekday,EOMONTH(@s_date,0)) dw
union all
--recursive query
select EOMONTH(eom,1) eom,datepart(weekday,EOMONTH(eom,1)) dw
from eom_tbl where eom<@e_date
)
select eom,dw,  
       --calculate last Wednesday (4)
       case when dw<4 then dateadd(dd,-3-dw,eom)
       else dateadd(dd,4-dw,eom) end lastWed,
       --extra check
       datepart(dw,case when dw<4 then dateadd(dd,-3-dw,eom)
       else dateadd(dd,4-dw,eom) end ) ddw
from eom_tbl
```